# (Question Marks) � instead of ÅÄÖ on old pages

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Hi for some months ago all of my website pages started showing question marks � instead of ÅÄÖ. The browser sets default encoding to Unicode, however if I change it to Western European it shows ÅÄÖ totally fine.

The weird thing is, all new entries on the website shows ÅÄÖ totally fine with Unicode. It's only the old pages that seem to have the problem.

I tried to set charset in .htaccess and headers but without any luck.

Any idea what to do here?

[Website with Unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLRyn.png)

[Website With Western European](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E1UG.png)

Comment: ‘Unicode’ is *not* an encoding (it’s a consortium). Some reading on the topic: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct encoding when you save the files. Your old files were probably saved with the wrong encoding.

Comment: I use forms to add data to the website. I always used the same form with the same settings. Never changed anything. :/. Even the Joomla admin area have questionmarks.